# Figuring out merge points in CVS

Tags: cvs

**Main Question:** Is there some way to figure out where/when (I'd take dates, tags, commits, basically anything) which branch was merged with another?

**Not so short explanation:** Since I'm stuck with CVS in several projects branching and merging is a constant uphill battle. In bigger teams of programmers with continous integration keeping track of branches (what they are for, who is involved, which files are likely to be changed, ...) and merging points (what has been integrated, and what has been changed since then) is a bigger problem than anyone had expected. While additional information would be appreciated, the first thing to know for merging those branches is where it was last merged (or if there was no merge in the past, the point the branch originated from).

**Possible solutions**

- *cvs rlog/log* will give me the version numbers of any file in any branch, though not when and of what version the branch originated from or if it was merged into any other branch.
- *`git log --graph --full-history --all`* will give me exactly what I want and need, but since git is not an option, this kind of jealousy will only keep me up at night ;)

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this out! You might be looking for

```
cvs history -x [type]
cvs history -T
```

-T should let you search by tags, -x G should get you information regarding successful merges

And here is the documentation for you:

http://cvsgui.sourceforge.net/howto/cvsdoc/cvs_16.html#SEC135

Hope this helps.